# Coding a Trailing Stoploss

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to code a Trailing Stoploss that starts 10 pips behind my entry once a target is hit 20 pips in profit. `trailingSL = high - 0.0030` for a long position is an easy enough concept, but how would I set up the target trigger and how would I get `trailingSL` to not move if price is going toward it? I'm wanting to do this without strategy.exit

Comment: The `strategy.exit` (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy{dot}exit) has trailing parameters. Does it not suitable for your?

Comment: I'm wanting to do this without strategy.exit